# Confusion in taking negation in nested statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

It is given that

> $\forall x \forall y [(x <y ) \rightarrow \exists z( x <z < y)]$

It is wanted to find the negation of given structure.

The answer is $\exists x \exists y [(x <y ) \wedge \forall z( x \geq z \vee  z \geq y)]$ . Where i stuck in is $( x \geq z \vee  z \geq y)$ , i see that because of $(x<z \wedge z<y)$ , when we take the negation of $(x<z \wedge z<y)$ , we obtain $( x \geq z \vee  z \geq y)$ . I want to ask that can we write $(x \geq z \geq y )$  instead of $( x \geq z \vee  z \geq y)$ .

If so , can we write $(x \geq z \geq y )$ as  $( x \geq z \wedge  z \geq y)$ , because we wrote $( x <z < y)$ as $(x<z \wedge z<y)$.

Comment: 1st step: move the negation sign inside: from $\lnot \forall$ to $\exists \lnot$

Comment: 2nd step: from $\lnot (P \to Q)$ to $(P \land \lnot Q)$

Comment: 3rd step: negate the inequality (it is a conjunction) with De Morgan.

Comment: $x \geq z \geq y$ is $x \geq z \land z \geq y$. There is an implicit $\text{and}$.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask that can we write $(x \geq z \geq y )$  instead of $( x \geq z \vee  z \geq y)$ .

No, because your suggestion is equivalent to $(x \geq z \land z \geq y)$ instead of $(x \geq z \lor z \geq y).$

For example, $z=3$ satisfies $(4 \geq z \lor z \geq 4)$ but not $7 \geq z \geq 4.$

---

**Addendum** (response to OP's follow-up query below)

OP: *We write negate $x >y $ as $x \leq y.$  Why cant we apply this to three or more variables? Why isn't $x<y<z$ negated as $ x \geq y \geq z$?*

By [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), $$\text{not} (x<y<z)\\
\equiv\text{not } (x<y \:\text{ and }\: y<z)\\
\equiv \text{not } (x<y) \:\text{ or }\: \text{not }(y<z)\\
\equiv x\geq y \:\text{ or }\: y\geq z\\
\not\equiv x\geq y \:\text{ and }\: y\geq z\\
\equiv x\geq y \geq z.$$

Comment: @STEWEN Please refer to the above addendum.